# Nodejs - Group large array objects by their timestamp property

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, timestamp, grouping

I have an array with a large amount of objects inside (around 200k to 1M entries). Each object looks like this:

```
Row {
  month_year_index: 'september_2019_2',
  localcol: 2019-09-13T00:52:16.847Z,
  datamap: {
    Curr1_mA: 769,
    Curr2_mA: 139,
    Curr3_mA: 0,
    P1_W: 75,
    P2_W: 0,
    P3_W: 0,
    P_Total_W: 75,
    U1N_Vx10: 2261,
    U2N_Vx10: 2330,
    U3N_Vx10: 2360
  }
}
```

I have these objects every 10 seconds and I need to group them by one timeUnit like this:

- 1 minute = 60000 ms
- 5 minutes = 300000 ms
- 15 minutes = 900000 ms
- 1 hour = 3600000 ms

So, basicaly I need to transform the original array into an array of arrays in which the first element of that array will be an array with the objects within this range (using 5 minutes as the time unit in example):

`[[first_object_timestamp, first_object_timestamp + 300000], [first_object_timestamp + 30000,first_object_timestamp + 600000]]`

If it's easier, you can transform the array into a single object with the datamap property having the average of the values, since I will have to do that anyways.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that make your scenario complex:

- Objects with `localcol` property for date
- Date needs to be parsed into a number format

For simplicity, my answer assumes the following things:

- It's just an array of numbers. Not an array of objects. You can modify this example to fit your scenario.
- The times go in ascending order

```js
const groupInterval = 5
const times = [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 14, 15, 18, 53, 402, 403]

const result = []
for (let i = 0; i < times.length;) {
  // Get starting time of group
  const firstTimeInGroup = Math.floor(times[i] / groupInterval) * groupInterval
  const group = []
  for (; times[i] < firstTimeInGroup + groupInterval; i++) {
    group.push(times[i])
  }
  result.push(group)
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, how can I make so that the intervals are fixed values:
Ex for 5 minutes:

[00:00:00, 00:05:00], [00:05:00, 00:10:00], [00:10:00, 00:15:00], etc.

Comment: I updated the snippet to have fixed values for intervals.